# I2C access on M41T00CAP RTC device

Tags: i2c, rtc

I am trying to access "M41T00CAP RTC" device through I2C. there are other I2C devices also, which  I am able to access perfectly. but in case of RTC device , I am not able to read the register correctly. The value read is random and not relevant. my I2C read function follows the exact I2C read protocol and is working well for other I2C devices. Does anyone have any idea about this device M41T00CAP?
Has anyone implemented this ?please share.

Comment: can you post a link to the M41T00CAP RTC in your question.  Also add some more information about your circuit.  What is the address of the RTC device?  Have you hot scope screen shots that show your master writing to the correct address?

Answer (score 1):

Randomness indicates that you are either
1: Reading an uninitialized device. This device "defaults to random" upon cold start.
2: Are reading the seconds register.
3: Haven't handled the address pointer correctly, it auto increments.